# Problem converting String->Float->String

Tags: java, swing

I have a JTable where i enter some values. This is the listener function to know if it has been made any change at the values, so i can update them. Values must have the format indicated (#.###), so I'm doing this fix to round the float to 3 decimal places if the client enter more than 3.

```
    private class CambioTablaPretratamientoListener implements TableModelListener{
    public void tableChanged(TableModelEvent e){
        try{
            if(enviarDatosADispositivo){
                TableModel model = (TableModel)e.getSource();
                float value = Float.parseFloat((String)model.getValueAt(e.getLastRow(), 1));
                DecimalFormat dec = new DecimalFormat("#.###");
                String aux = dec.format(value);
                if(model.getValueAt(e.getLastRow(), 1).equals(aux))
                    return;
                else
                    model.setValueAt(aux, e.getLastRow(), 1);
                value = Float.parseFloat(aux);

                String nombreAtributo = (String)model.getValueAt(e.getLastRow(), 0);

                nodoAModificar.setPretratamientUserParameter(nombreAtributo, value);     
            }
        }catch(BusinessException ex){
            ex.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
}
```

Code seems to work at first, because it rounds and the number appears in the table, but the value is not getting updated. I guess I'm doing something wrong with the DecimalFormat, because if I leave the function like this one, it works:

```
    private class CambioTablaPretratamientoListener implements TableModelListener{
    public void tableChanged(TableModelEvent e){
        try{
            if(enviarDatosADispositivo){
                TableModel model = (TableModel)e.getSource();
                float value = Float.parseFloat((String)model.getValueAt(e.getLastRow(), 1));
                String nombreAtributo = (String)model.getValueAt(e.getLastRow(), 0);

                nodoAModificar.setPretratamientUserParameter(nombreAtributo, value);     
            }
        }catch(BusinessException ex){
            ex.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
}
```

And finall

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you use BigDecimal, you could actually truncate the numbers, instead of trying to use Float's (lack of) precision.

Comment: It would mean big changes in the code, because it is an old project I inherited from the former programmers. Can't I fix it to run with Floats?

Answer (score 2):

You seem to think that converting a floating-point number to a String and back again can cause it to have a definite number of decimal places. This is fallacious. FP values don't have *any* decimal places. They have *binary* places. These only correspond to fixed numbers of decimal places if the fractional part is a negative power of 2, e.g. 0.5, 0.125, 0.0625, etc.

Comment: I know how a FP is made from binary places, but if I round it through a String conversion, I don't see why it shouldn't work. Anyway, how can i make this in a different way?

Comment: @Roman Rdgz That's odd, because I have just told you why it doesn't work.

Comment: @Roman Rdgz only for certain values. It cannot possibly work for all values, for the reasons given.

Answer (score 2):

Instead, apply your [`DecimalFormat`](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/text/DecimalFormat.html) as a [custom table cell renderer](http://download.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/table.html#editrender).